# tensorflow Object_Detection Training through model_main.py，Appear TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I used the training script provided on GitHub, "TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects" appeared during the training process, other people add list() to category_index.values() in model_lib.py

I tried, but it didn't work. Why?

The version I'm currently using is
Tensorflow 1.9.0
Python 3.6
Tensorflow models and Object_Detection API were recently downloaded on GitHub

Please take a look at this problem for me. Thank you very much.

Here is my error message：

```
2018-12-07 10:24:06.572700: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1306] Invalid argument: TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 358, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 207, in evaluate
    self._detection_boxes_list)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 118, in LoadAnnotations
    results.dataset['categories'] = copy.deepcopy(self.dataset['categories'])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[1], [1,300,300,3], [1,300,300,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,100], [1,100,4], [1,100,1], [1,100,1], [1,100], [1,100], [1,100], [1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/evaluation.py", line 212, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 577, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1053, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1144, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1129, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1201, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 981, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[1], [1,300,300,3], [1,300,300,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,100], [1,100,4], [1,100,1], [1,100,1], [1,100], [1,100], [1,100], [1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]

Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "model_main.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main.py", line 109, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 531, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 681, in run_local
    eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 453, in evaluate
    input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1346, in _evaluate_build_graph
    model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 987, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    return estimator_util.parse_input_fn_result(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/util.py", line 110, in parse_input_fn_result
    result = iterator.get_next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 373, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1745, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[1], [1,300,300,3], [1,300,300,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,100], [1,100,4], [1,100,1], [1,100,1], [1,100], [1,100], [1,100], [1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 358, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 207, in evaluate
    self._detection_boxes_list)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 118, in LoadAnnotations
    results.dataset['categories'] = copy.deepcopy(self.dataset['categories'])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects


     [[Node: PyFunc_3 = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_5", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3/_1743 = _HostRecv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_221_cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main.py", line 109, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 531, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 681, in run_local
    eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 460, in evaluate
    output_dir=self.eval_dir(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1386, in _evaluate_run
    config=self._session_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/evaluation.py", line 212, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 689, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 721, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 824, in end
    self._final_ops, feed_dict=self._final_ops_feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 358, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 207, in evaluate
    self._detection_boxes_list)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 118, in LoadAnnotations
    results.dataset['categories'] = copy.deepcopy(self.dataset['categories'])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects


     [[Node: PyFunc_3 = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_5", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3/_1743 = _HostRecv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_221_cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'PyFunc_3', defined at:
  File "model_main.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main.py", line 109, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 447, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 531, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 681, in run_local
    eval_result, export_results = evaluator.evaluate_and_export()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 886, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 453, in evaluate
    input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1348, in _evaluate_build_graph
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1107, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 418, in model_fn
    eval_config, category_index.values(), eval_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 848, in get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators
    eval_dict))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 368, in get_estimator_eval_metric_ops
    first_value_op = tf.py_func(first_value_func, [], tf.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 384, in py_func
    func=func, inp=inp, Tout=Tout, stateful=stateful, eager=False, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 227, in _internal_py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_script_ops.py", line 128, in py_func
    "PyFunc", input=input, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 358, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 207, in evaluate
    self._detection_boxes_list)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 118, in LoadAnnotations
    results.dataset['categories'] = copy.deepcopy(self.dataset['categories'])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects


     [[Node: PyFunc_3 = PyFunc[Tin=[], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_5", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3/_1743 = _HostRecv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_221_cond_3/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/3", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: I don't know if this still an issue for you, but this is actually a bug and was corrected on newer versions of `models`

Comment: @Bob.Mu Is this still an issue for you? Does [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/issues/385) reference help you?